# Parametric curve with boundary conditions and "stable" coefficients

Tags: functional-analysis, analytic-geometry

I'm trying to build a 2D parametric curve. Let's say $(x(s),y(s))$ such that
$$\left(\frac{dx}{ds}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{ds}\right)^2=1$$
Then with known Dirichlet and Neumann boundary conditions on both ends:
$$x(0)=x_0,y(0)=y_0$$
$$\frac{dx}{ds}(0)=\cos(\theta_0),\frac{dy}{ds}(0)=\sin(\theta_0)$$
At $s=L$ we have simplified values like:
$$x(L)=0,y(L)=0$$
$$\frac{dx}{ds}(0)=1,\frac{dy}{ds}(0)=0$$

On top of that, let's suppose we started from another $s=l$ between $0$ and $L$, and call the new curve $(x_{new}(s),y_{new}(s))$ with boundary conditions at $s=l$ being:

$$x_{new}(l)=x(l),y_{new}(l)=y(l)$$
$$\frac{dx_{new}}{ds}(l)=\frac{dx}{ds}(l),\frac{dy_{new}}{ds}(l)=\frac{dy}{ds}(l)$$

I want to make sure that the curve stays the same for the remaining portion, i.e.:
$$x_{new}(s)=x(s)$$
$$y_{new}(s)=y(s)$$
For $s\in[l,L]$

I want to create a "docking" control with constant speed and the only thing I can control is the steering $\theta$ and the things I know are my current position $x$, $y$ and my direction $\theta$. I want to dock to $(0,0)$ looking towards the x-axis in the positive direction ($\theta=0$).

I looked at third order polynomials but the speed norm is not always 1. So the coefficients change during travel.
I was wondering if there are known functions of that sort that someone might know.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I "built" a piecewise curve like an arc circle in the beginning, a straight line and a final arc circle for docking. But are there more "elegant" solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Natural /intrinsic equation of curves should be used.

There are many curves to choose from depending on how you wish to vary curvature with respect to arc length... to clear obstacles, to reverse etc.

Try some curves like hypo/epi- cycloids,trochoids, DeLaunay unduloids, clothoids etc., the latter were reported employed to steer/dock /park BMW automobiles into narrow parking lines using predictable paths...

As an exercise take the example of a of a cycloid whose intrinsic ODE

$$ \sin \phi= \sin \alpha -\frac{s}{4 a};\quad  4 a \cos \phi\dfrac{d \phi }{ds}= -1; $$

involves slope $\phi$ and $s$ the arc length, $\phi_i $ initial slope $a$ the rolling circle radius, and $\phi' $ the instantaneous curvature. At the cusp point automobile stops and reverses towards the opposite direction. The ODE can be integrated with usual RK4 method.

[image]

```
a=1;phi=1.57;xi=0.1a;yi=0. a;smax=7.9999a;
NDSolve[{PH'[s] Cos[PH[s]]==-1/(4a),X'[s]==Cos[PH[s]],Y'[s]==Sin[PH[s]],PH[0]==phi,X[0]==xi,Y[0]==yi},{PH,X,Y},{s,0,smax}];
{ph[u_],x[u_],y[u_]}={PH[u],X[u],Y[u]}/.First[%]; ParametricPlot[{x[s],y[s]},{s,0,smax},GridLines->Automatic]
ParametricPlot[{s,Sin[ph[s]] - Sin[phi]},{s,0,smax},GridLines->Automatic]
```

More than initial value formulations (IVP), boundary value constraints/conditions (BVP), shoot through techniques are useful I believe for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Saying that you have a unit speed is equivalent to parameterize your curve with curvilinear abscissa (our use of letter "s" shows that you are fully conscious of that).

If your objective is to have a numerical solution, you can work by solving a system of differential equations (I can give you an  interesting example I have been working on), using a Runge Kutta solver (with Matlab for example), but...

Yes to your question: there exists "on the shelf" a family of curves called **Cornu spirals** or "clothoids" with hopefully the good degrees of freedom for your docking conditions in particular. They can be adapted to numerical computation. I advise you to download this [article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/292669884_The_Clothoid_Computation_A_Simple_and_Efficient_Numerical_Algorithm/figures?lo=1) in order to understand a certain number of facts about these curves.

Remark: when you mention "third degree polynomials", are you thinking to Spline/Bezier curves ?

Waiting for your comments.

Comment: No comment on my answer ? As I said I can give you an interesting example (connected to curves that are level curves of complex functions)

Comment: I would like to see please

Comment: @Narasimham I will do it as soon as the OP is responding.

Comment: I am very very sorry for repying late. @JeanMarie, I was reading through all of the article and documentation on other websites about Cornu Spirals. These are amazing!
I would love to see examples of it.
I am trying to see if I can find a differential equation that yields the clothoid as result. But the differential equation would be preferred to be non-dependent of its "history" but rather its current position and speed direction.
Like such : $\frac{d\theta}{ds}=f(\theta,x,y)$ without any $s$ for example. But what I see in literature is an ODE dependent on $s$.

Comment: Clothoids are like when you drive at a constant speed in your car and you change your steering wheel from one steering angle to another steering angle in a linear fashion over time. You want your "integral" of steering angle to be equal to the difference of $\theta$ from $0$ to $L$.

Comment: Yes, I see that you deeply understand as well on the theoretical side as on the intuitive point of view! I will continue this exchange in a rather short time.

Comment: I am using Matlab to see how clothoids would work and let's say we have three parameters $x_0, y_0, \theta_0$ and as such, clothoid gives me three degrees of freedom that are the coefficients of the second order polynomial in the angle. Let's swap the coordinates such as we start instead of ending at $(0,0)$. I found it's a bit easier like this.
$$x(s)=L\int_0^\frac{s}{L} cos(S(a(1-S)+\theta_f))dS$$
$$y(s)=L\int_0^\frac{s}{L} sin(S(a(1-S)+\theta_f))dS$$
Degrees of freedom are $L$, $a$ and $\theta_f$. $L$ is quite easy to get, $\theta_f$ is given but $a$ is a hard one to crack.

Comment: I plotted $\alpha=tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y(L)}{x(L)}\right)$ to get rid of $L$. It gives a "mostly" linear function approximately equal to:
$$\alpha=\frac{\theta_f}{2}-\frac{a}{4}+O(1)$$. That $O(1)$ is a really weird and interesting function to be honest! But I hope for my own interest, the approximation is good enough to control motion. I am going to continue giving updates too. Thank you for your help.

Comment: It is a pleasure of this site. Thanks for your thanks.